# JaCoCo plugin between Maven and Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to run my project using Ant both for unit test and code coverage over the tested code and reports of these two. Before I used Maven, but I need a report customization and find it easier with Ant. JUnit was imported automatically when I generate the build.xml from Eclipse :

```
<pathelement location="../../../../.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar"/>
```

No I would like to add also the JaCoCo in my Ant build so I can run both Junit and the latter at the same time. In a lot of guides I find on the web i always find something like:

```
<!-- Step 1: Import JaCoCo Ant tasks -->
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="../../../lib/jacocoant.jar" />
</taskdef>
```

I can easily find the jacocoant.jar file if I download the JaCoCo from the official file, but I would like to download it automatically from a dependency manager like Maven (or similar) but, after a lot of tries, I can't find the corresponding of "jacocoant.jar" through the Maven dependencies, so at the moment I can't add to JaCoCo to my Ant build.

There's a way to make this possible?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JaCoCo homepage](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) contains link on [documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/index.html), which contains page ["Maven Repository"](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html):

> Following JAR files are available:
>
> ```
> Group ID   | Artifact ID    | Classifier | Description
> -----------+----------------+------------+-------------
> ...
> org.jacoco | org.jacoco.ant |            | Ant Tasks
> org.jacoco | org.jacoco.ant | nodeps     | Ant Tasks (all dependencies included)
> ...
> ```

The last one is being exactly `jacocoant.jar`:

```
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco/0.8.1/jacoco-0.8.1.zip
unzip jacoco-0.8.1.zip
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.8.1/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.1-nodeps.jar
sha256sum lib/jacocoant.jar org.jacoco.ant-0.8.1-nodeps.jar

eb375296cb836c202f35b711fee2a41bbeb447b80e54dd1fd05ef6c1d75774e3  lib/jacocoant.jar
eb375296cb836c202f35b711fee2a41bbeb447b80e54dd1fd05ef6c1d75774e3  org.jacoco.ant-0.8.1-nodeps.jar
```